# How to extract selected images from bs_presentImagePickerController

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

Using bs_presentImagePickerController for multiple image selection, but not getting how to pick the selected images. Below is the code:

```
bs_presentImagePickerController(vc, animated: false,
                                    select: { (asset: PHAsset) -> Void in
                                        print("Selected: \(asset)")
        }, deselect: { (asset: PHAsset) -> Void in
            print("Deselected: \(asset)")
        }, cancel: { (assets: [PHAsset]) -> Void in
            print("Cancel: \(assets)")
        }, finish: { (assets: [PHAsset]) -> Void in
            print("Finish: \(assets)")
            kAppDelegate.imageSelected = true
        }, completion:{})
```

Please guide.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30852200

Comment: Yes got answer from here "http://stackoverflow.com/a/30852200/2545292"