# Converting PHAsset to UIImage and displaying it to user

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using the `BSImagePicker` Image Picker controller ([See here](https://github.com/mikaoj/BSImagePicker))

The image picker controller returns PHAsset rather than UIImage, so I found out how to convert PHAsset to UIImage using this function:

[PHAsset to UIImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30812057/phasset-to-uiimage)

```
func getAssetThumbnail(asset: PHAsset) -> UIImage {
    let manager = PHImageManager.default()
    let option = PHImageRequestOptions()
    var thumbnail = UIImage()
    option.isSynchronous = true
    manager.requestImage(for: asset, targetSize: CGSize(width: 100, height: 100), contentMode: .aspectFit, options: option, resultHandler: {(result, info)->Void in
        thumbnail = result!
    })
    return thumbnail
}
```

Issue is that, I want to return the targetSize of `PHImageManagerMaximumSize`.  Althought when this happens, I get an errorr`This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread after the engine was accessed from the main thread. This can lead to engine corruption and weird crashes.`

The error doesn't occur when I set `targetSize` to `CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)`

Answer (score 1):

Just you need to do to avoid your error is to force the application to modify the auto layout on the main thread. You can for example use a dispatcher in the main queue when you set your image.
For example:

```
let image = self.getAssetThumbnail(asset: <YourPHAsset>)

        DispatchQueue.main.async {

            self.imageView.image = image
        }
```

The error should occur also when you use a `targetSize`... Strange...